# R code with > symbol

Tags: r

Can someone please kindly explain this line of code?  I don't quite seem to understand how it works?

```
    decision <- (a > 0.5) * 1
    a <- 0.3
    decision
    # [1] 1
    a <- 0.001
    decision
    # [1] 1
    a <- 100
    decision
    # [1] 1
```

if a is 0.3, I get 1.
if a is 0.001, I get 1.
if a is 100, I get 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to create a function named `decision`? What happens in your code is that `decision` is set at the time of its creation, and never modified after that. You already had set `a` to some value before running the code that you showed us, and `decision` was set based on that.

This is how to create a function. It should take `a` as a parameter, btw.

```
decision <- function(a) (a > 0.5) * 1
decision(0.3)
# 0
decision(0.001)
# 0
decision(100)
# 1
```

Comment: ah, yes, that's essentially what I want to do.  So for this function, if a is greater than 0.5, the decision will be 1?  Is this correct?